# Statement of the Term-Test for convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I am refering to the term test

[Term-Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test)

which states $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n < \infty \Rightarrow a_n \to 0$. But what about for example $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n$ which is convergent, but there the series $a_n = (-1)^n$ has no limit. So a correct statement of the Term-Test would be
$$
 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \Rightarrow \limsup a_n = 0.
$$
Right? But I nowhere find this statement with limes superior instead of the normal limes?

EDIT: Changed $a_n = 1 + (-1)^n$ to $a_n = (-1)^n$.

Comment: There is a difference between being bounded and convergent. The series you give is bounded but not convergent. There is nothing wrong with the definition.

Comment: How do you prove that $\sum_{n\geq 1} (-1)^n$ converges...? If you can't find this statement anywhere, it is because, although it is true, it is a very weak form of the real statement whose conclusion if $\lim a_n=0$.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, we say that the series $\sum u_n$ is convergent if its partial sum $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n u_k$ is convergent.

Now the sequence $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k$ isn't convergent since its subsequences $s_{2n+1}=-1$ and $s_{2n}=0$ had different limits so the given series is not convergent.

Answer (score 1):

The series $\sum a_n$ where $a_n=(-1)^n$ is not convergent. The partial sums bounce around, they do not settle down.

The only way I can see to get a convergent series through devices like the ones in the OP is with $b_n=(1+(-1)^{2n+1})$. But that's just a peculiar way of writing $0$. If we write down the terms and remove the parentheses, we get non-convergence.

Answer (score 0):

The series here is not convergent, the n-th partial sum equals $2\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor$ which goes to infinity.

Comment: yes, I changed the series!